# Jquery's .load() to get data from MySQL database by specific ID in the URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm a beginner in Jquery/PHP. I'm trying to use **.load()** to get some data from the database by specific ID in the URL, but i can't get it to work.

I'll talk about the problem i'm facing after i post both of my codes.

Here is the **index.html** file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>People Info</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <b>People Info:</b>
    <ol id="new-projects"></ol>

    <script>
    $( "#new-projects" ).load( "GetDataPeople.php" );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my **GetDataPeople.php** file:

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$db_name = "people";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error){
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['FirstName'];
    echo $row['LastName'];
    echo $row['Phone'];
}
?>
```

The **GetDataPeople.php** itself works fine, i mean when i try to type "**GetDataPeople.php?id=2**" in the URL, i get the data that has the ID number 2, which is exactly what i want to get out of this.

But when i try to use "**index.html?id=2**" it says that there is something wrong with the query (I think because it didn't use the ID in the URL. I tried to use a simple query like : SELECT * FROM people and it worked fine. So yah i think what caused the error is because it didn't read the URL).

So i'd really like to know how to fix it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your html you are requesting the php page without a id parameter. That's why you are receiving a undefined variable error from the php code

Comment: `load( "GetDataPeople.php?id=ID" )`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery automatically determines whether load() does a get or a post.

Passing a variable to $_GET['id'] would work like this:

```
<script>
  var id = 1; 
  $( "#new-projects" ).load( "GetDataPeople.php?id=" + id );
</script>
```

A post to $_POST['id'] would look like this:

```
<script>
  var id = 1;
  $( "#new-projects" ).load( "GetDataPeople.php",{ "id": id } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the wanted id in the url you give to `load()` function, not when you call the index.html... You just have to dynamicaly give the id as you did : `?id=x` in the `load()` function url.

for example, clicking on a button with the id="2" would call getdatapeople.php?id=2

If you have to load it dynamicaly, what i assume.

```
<button class="btn-data" data-people-id="2">click me</button>
```

script:

```
url = 'getpeopledata.php';

$('.btn-data').click(function(){

    var id = $(this).data('people-id');
    url += '?id=' + id;
    $(some-element)load(url);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will fix your issue.

```
<script>

function GetParameterValues(param) {  
            var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');  
            for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {  
                var urlparam = url[i].split('=');  
                if (urlparam[0] == param) {  
                    return urlparam[1];  
                }  
            }  
        }  

 $( "#new-projects" ).load( "GetDataPeople.php?id=" + GetParameterValues('id');
<script>
```